# How to make CKEditor reconise AJAX page link

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, ckeditor

I use CKE on my website. It is an full AJAX engine and all works fine with CKE, no problem with AJAX.

My little problem were when i want to work on links.

I edit an area, write a link like it :

```
<a href='#!idPage' title='Name of page' >Name of page</a>
```

No problem to record it and use it.
But when i come back to edit it, CKE don't recognize it !
And all the input are empty, no name, no link, ... i must write them again :(

For CKE it is not an HTTP link and not an ANCHOR too.
It not start with **http** or **#** but **#!** like *GOOGLE* advice to use.

How can we fix that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Today i try to make some modif in CKE link.js

```
edit line 80 : urlRegex = /^((?:(?:http|https|ftp|news):\/\/)|(?:#!))?(.*)$/,
add line 375 [ '#!\u200E', '#!' ], 
edit line 401 : urlOnChangeProtocol = /^(?:(?:http|https|ftp|news):\/\/)|(?:#!)(?=.)/i,
```

It is better, but always not edit my link :(

Comment: I found the solution 
edit line 79 : anchorRegex = /^#([^!].*)$/,

So excellent ... and so bad CKE team never think to add AJAX link support :(